# Regex java need some tips

Tags: java

So I have to use Regex for the name of a character, where the name has to start with a capital and can only exist out of letters, apostrophe's and spaces.
And I dont know how to start, could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Start by learning about regular expressions.

Comment: Have you tried a simple regex tutorial?

Comment: Go through this http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

I suppose your character name is stored in a String variable. For that you can use the `String.matches()` function, which accepts a regex String parameter.

To create the required regex you will have to combine the folowing:

`[A-Z]` for the capital letter

`[a-z' ]+` for the remaining characters.

Note that when using those in Java you'll need to add some escape characters

You can experiment with regular expressions here: http://www.regexr.com